# Get jar-with-dependencies using ansible maven_artifact

Tags: maven, ansible, jar-with-dependencies

**Is it possible to get a Java *jar-with-dependencies* using `ansible` package `maven_artifact`?**

Now for a bit of a context:

1. I have a simple Java application. This means I need to produce a *jar-with-dependencies* type of jar for this app to be executable as a stand alone.
2. I'm pushing my jar using `mvn deploy` in a registry (in my case: Nexus)
3. I'm using **Ansible** to deploy my app and it seems to be a sensible choice to use `maven_artifact` package (I suppose it manages idempotence better then I would).

Very logically, when I do this, I get the simple jar (without all dependencies) and not the *jar-with-dependenices*.

Comment: Are you pushing the _jar-with-dependencies_ to Nexus? If so, you could probably download it using the `classifier` parameter of the `maven_artifact` module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/maven_artifact_module.html

Comment: Nice call. I'm checking it.

Comment: BTW, documentation is absolutely NOT explicit on what a classifier is: "classifier: The maven classifier coordinate"

Comment: Agreed, there's very little info there. More info on the classifier here: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies

Comment: IT WORKED AWESOME! Willing to give you full credit for this. Please post an answer so I can vote you up and flag as correct answer.

Comment: Answer posted - happy that I could be of help!

Comment: Agreed. I should have known better and guess that the classifier is a native maven property! Thx so much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the following steps:

- Make sure that your `jar-with-dependencies` is uploaded to Nexus with a specific `classifier`, e.g. `full`. For more info on the `classifier`, please check the [Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies).
- Use the [Ansible maven_artifact module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/maven_artifact_module.html)'s `classifier` attribute to point to your `full` artifact.

Comment: I actually didn't even bother renaming it as `full`. `classifier: jar-with-dependencies` worked awesome. Jar was downloaded and renamed by `maven_artifact` as a normal jar.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my vamp of the answer:

File organisation should be:

`roles/fetch-my-awesome-jar/tasks/main.yml`

And content:

```
---
- name: fetch my awesome jar
  maven_artifact:
    group_id: my.awesome.group.id
    artifact_id: my-awesom-artifact-id
    version: my.awesome.version.number
    classifier: jar-with-dependencies
    extension: jar
    repository_url: http://my-local-nexus:<port>/repository/my-awesome-repo/
    username: my-username
    password: my-password
    dest: my-awesome-target-directory
```

The version of `maven_artifact` I'm using has removed the `jar-with-dependencies` classifier.